# navbar{display: none} class not applied using bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There are three `.navbar` bootstrap classes in `bootstrap.css` file.

- first `.navbar` rule sets `display` property to `none`.
- second `.navbar` rule sets position, `height`, `margin` and `border`.
- third `.navbar` rule is encapsulated into a media rule `min-width: 768px`, and sets the `border-radius`.

Now If I create a `div` with `class="navbar"`, I expect it to be hidden. But it is not. I am not able to find out why the first `.navbar` is not getting applied.

Comment: why not add a class `hidden` ? `<div class="navbar hidden"> </div>`, I don't think navbar class first rule is to set display:none in the first place.

Comment: add a JSFiddle, where we can see you HTML&CSS.

Comment: @Holybreath - I can do that but I want to understand why the first rule is not getting applied. This rule .navbar{display: none} is there in the css code.

Comment: @panther - just <div class="navbar">This should be hidden</div> inside the body tag.

Comment: @Sunny Singh: do you have in your CSS `.navbar {display: none}`?

Comment: @panther - Yes, this rule is there in bootstrap.css. My stylesheet is blank.

Comment: Add JSFiddle link with a part of HTML we speak about, CSS with this declaration and show me that it doesn´t work. Error has to be elsewhere.

Comment: What browser are you viewing in?

Comment: @panther [link](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6194/)

Comment: @panther do you agree that there are three .navbar rules, and the first one is `.navbar {display: none;}` ?

Comment: There is no `.navbar { display:none; }`

Comment: @Holybreath see here [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) on github, line number - 241

Comment: @Sunny Singh: it's just for print.

Comment: @Holybreath - sorry. I figured out with the help of @andyb. its inside `@media print {}`. Thanks for the help

Comment: @panther - sorry. I figured out with the help of @andyb. its inside `@media print {}`. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [CSS file](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css) the `.navbar { display:none }` is inside `@media print {}` so the browser will only apply that class when printing or using print preview.

Answer (score 1):

Display:none; is under media print that is why